# Calculate moving average for the last 7 calendar days if there are some missing dates

Tags: sql, teradata, moving-average

I want to calculate the average of sales per article_no for the last 7 calendar days.
For example, for 30.01.2023 will be the value for sell_val for 30.01.2023 and the next 6 values -> column avg_sell_val and so on.

[this is my table (article_sales)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBMi6.png)

In the first place, I used this code (I work with Teradata SQL Assistant) :

```
SELECT
art_no,
date_of_day,
sell_val,
, AVG(COALESCE(sell_val, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.art_no ORDER BY date_of_day DESC ROWS  BETWEEN  CURRENT ROW AND 6 FOLLOWING ) AS avg_sell
FROM article_sales
```

but then I realized that, if 26.01.2023 is missing, it will take also 23.01.20233 as the 7th row even if it is not part of the last 7 calendar days.

Is there a method by which I can take the last 7 calendar days and if a day is missing to put 0 on sell_val, like it is in the column next to avg_sell_val?

I tried to use

```
AVG(COALESCE(sell_val_nsp, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY s.art_no, s.var_tu_key, s.company_hier_id, s.customer_need_group_id ORDER BY date_of_day DESC RANGE  BETWEEN  INTERVAL CURRENT ROW AND '6 DAY' FOLLOWING )AS avg_sell
```

but I got an error like "Expected the word RESET or ')' after ORDER BY" and I couldn't find anything like this on the internet.

Comment: do not use images, share schema, data sample and expected results in usable table or dml/ddl script

Comment: @Horaciux sorry, I didn't know how to add an example and also the expected result in order to be clear

Comment: Teradata does not currently support RANGE for the ROWS clause. The classic solution is to outer join a calendar table to the data to fill in missing values. Current releases of Teradata also have proprietary [time-series aware aggregation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/Teradata-VantageTM-Time-Series-Tables-and-Operations-17.20/Time-Series-Aggregates-and-SELECT-Extensions) options.

Comment: @Cristina096 - you can [create tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) in your post, which is ideal for showing sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's just one row per art_no/date_of_day in your data there are two possible solutions.

Use [Time Series Aggregation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/Teradata-VantageTM-Time-Series-Tables-and-Operations-17.20/Time-Series-Aggregates-and-SELECT-Extensions) to *create* the missing rows:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT
      art_no
      -- time series aggregation returns a PERIOD (on a non-Time Series Table based on TimeStamps)
     ,Cast(Begin($Td_TimeCode_Range) AS DATE) AS date_of_day
     ,Sum(sell_val) AS sell_val
   FROM vt

-- without WHERE all missing days since the min data_of_day per art_no will be created
-- with a filter all missing days since DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd' for each art_no will be created
 --  WHERE date_of_day >= DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'

   GROUP BY TIME (Days(1) AND art_no) -- for each art_no & day
         USING TIMECODE (date_of_day) -- datatime column for time series
         FILL (NULLS)  -- fill missing rows with zeros
 )
SELECT art_no
  ,date_of_day
  ,sell_val
  ,Avg(Coalesce(sell_val,0))
   Over(PARTITION BY art_no
        ORDER BY date_of_day -- now there's no more missing date
        ROWS 6 Preceding)
FROM cte
QUALIFY sell_val IS NOT NULL -- remove the missing dates
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
;
```

If your query creating `article_sales` is already an aggregation this is probably the easiest way (and can be adjusted to weeks/months/etc.).

Or calculate how many rows are in the 7 day window:

```
SELECT
   art_no
  ,date_of_day
  ,sell_val

   -- looks complex, but it's just one step in Explain
   -- lots of cut&paste&modify, just double check if you modified accordingly 
  ,CASE
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,6) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Avg(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 6 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,5) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Avg(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 5 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,4) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Avg(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 4 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,3) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Avg(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 3 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,2) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Avg(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 2 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,1) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Avg(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 1 Preceding)
      ELSE sell_val
    END
FROM vt
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
;
```

This works well but it's limited to a small range of days.

Which one is more efficient also depends on the percentage of missing rows.

**Edit:**

Caution, Q2 does not return the same result! If you want to add a missing row as zero to your average you have to switch the calculation to

```
   ,CASE
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,6) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Sum(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 6 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,5) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Sum(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 5 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,4) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Sum(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 4 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,3) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Sum(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 3 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,2) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Sum(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 2 Preceding)
      WHEN date_of_day - 6 <= Lag(date_of_day,1) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day) THEN Sum(sell_val) Over (PARTITION BY art_no ORDER BY date_of_day ROWS 1 Preceding)
      ELSE sell_val
    END / 7
```

**Edit 2:**

Caution again, now the first 7 rows per art_no will show different values, because Q2 assumes 7 days even before the first date and Q1 is based on less than 7 days. How to fix depends on waht you really want :-)

Comment: If you tried both variations, can you provide some details about performance?

Comment: Caution, my 2nd query returns a different result, see edit

Comment: The first one seemed more complex and I couldn't use CTE in my query, so I chose the second one. Thank your for the edit, I had also noticed it and what I needed was to always divide by 7.  :)